# Referring to one of the coauthors--should I simply use his or her name?

Tags: style, academic-writing, collaboration

For example, Wang and Zimmermann are writing a research paper together. In their paper, they want to refer to Zimmermann's previous work (possibly with other coauthors).

Should they write "In the second author's previous work, ..."
or "In Zimmerman's previous work,..."?

The second option is not making clear that they are referring to one of the present coauthors, since there are so many Zimmermann's in the world. Perhaps, the reader should figure that out by referring to the References list?

Answer (score 3):

The clearest method is to refer to..

> The co-author Zimmerman's previous work.

That contains both the name and the fact of authorship.  It is also a common practice.

It is likely that this other work will appear in a reference list in your paper.  That list will typically contain the initials of the author as well as the surname, thus also indicating that the work is by an author of the present work.  However, as you say, there are many Zimmermans - there are also several Zimmermans with the same initials.  Explicit reference will remove doubt.

Comment: And make sure to say "Dr. Zimmerman" if this is the case

Comment: @Alexander: No, that is not considered appropriate in scientific papers.

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like "...one of the authors conducted a study [citation]..." which identifies the author indirectly.  I have seen less formally something along the lines of "... one of us (Zimmerman) employed a modified test protocol..." and sometimes something a little stodgier like "one of the authors of the present work (Zimmerman) previously avoided the use of neutral density filters"...  There are many options.

Comment: Many journals will reject *one of us* as it is first person.  Better to use *one of the present authors* or similar.